# JPA DAO integration test not throwing exception when duplicate object saved?

Tags: hibernate, spring, jpa, junit, persistence

I am in the process of unit testing a DAO built with Spring/JPA and Hibernate as the provider.

Prior to running the test, DBUnit inserted a User record with username "poweruser" -- username is the primary key in the users table.  Here is the integration test method:

```
@Test
@ExpectedException(EntityExistsException.class)
public void save_UserTestDataSaveUserWithPreExistingId_EntityExistsException() {
    User newUser = new UserImpl("poweruser");

    newUser.setEmail("kuser@null.com");
    newUser.setFirstName("New");
    newUser.setLastName("User");
    newUser.setPassword("secret");

    dao.persist(newUser);
}
```

I have verified that the record is in the database at the start of this method.  Not sure if this is relevant, but if I do a `dao.flush()` at the end of this method I get the following exception:

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: 
    Could not execute JDBC batch update
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you're using the transactional integration tests? These tests rollback at the end of each test method, so you are indeed missing the flush.

I don't know if this is useful, but if you were autogenerating the ID, then a flush would happen at the persist() because a trip to the database is needed to get the generated ID. But if you're assigning your own ID's, then the flush is delayed until the commit, as you've seen.

Comment: I am using the transactional integration tests.  Great point, I hadn't thought of the autogenerated key.  However my entire app uses application assigned UUIDs as surrogate primary key.  So flush() is my new friend....

Answer (score 1):

Apparently unless flush is called explicitly or implicitly (via a query or a commit) then any potential exception will not be thrown.  So I guess I am going to have to call flush() in all of my integration tests that modify data.

Comment: Look at http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/api/org/hibernate/Session.html#setFlushMode(org.hibernate.FlushMode)

Comment: Its good stuff, but it still doesn't talk about *when* a persistence exception is thrown...e.g. during persist() or during flush().  I just think its a little weird that I have to call flush() in all  my integration tests...is this normal?